# Cannot access properties file in tomcat - linux

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets, properties-file

I have placed a `.properties` file in the `webapps` folder of `tomcat` but am not able to access it.

My `servlet` is in directory under `webapps`.

Do I have to change my java code to look into parent directory?

```
 private static final ResourceBundle ldap = ResourceBundle.getBundle("js_ldap");
```

Comment: We place ours in the Tomcat folder - it means you can edit them and the edits survive a new release. You can find the path to that folder using `System.getProperty("catalina.home");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the file into your **classpath** (src/main/resources/anything.properties), if the file is **shipped** with your application. Load it as usual, using ResourceBundle or Properties class.

If the file is **shared** across many apps, and it is changed often or server specific, then put it in a directory anywhere on your server, give the right permissions, and load it with an absoluth path using (Classloader).**getResourcesAsStream**(...). Dont put it into the server directory, since it might be removed if someone changes the server.

As I can see you are trying to load LDAP properties. If you are looking for a way to authenticate users, create a [JNDIRealm](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm).

Answer (score 2):

To access the file on your application directory, you should use the following:

```
private static final ResourceBundle ldap = ResourceBundle.getBundle("js_ldap.properties");
```

Concerning the placement of the properties file, I don't think it's a good idea to put it in the webapps directory. Consider, that you as a developer won't have access to this directory on production environments.

A better solution would be to include these files on a jar, and put this jar on Tomcat's classpath. This way the properties files could be shared by many applications.

Comment: this works if I place .properties file in my application directory but I don't want to copy/paste .properties file every time I create a new application

Comment: @stefan so I cannot use ResourceBundle and specify absolute path?